# rCharts output to string

Tags: rcharts

I would like to get output of below into a html string.

```
library(rCharts)  
p2 <- nPlot(mpg ~ wt, group = 'cyl', data = mtcars, type = 'scatterChart')
p2$xAxis(axisLabel = 'Weight')
p2$chart(size = '#! function(d){return d.gear} !#')
html <- p2$print()
html
NULL
```

How to get the complete html file which gets launched into a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can capture the html as a string using the `render` method

```
html <- p2$render()
```

Comment: for p2$print() - this gives me <div id...</div> <scirpt>..</script> But it goes to the console not to a variable.  while when I do p2$html() I get only <script>...</script> part. Is there any way of getting div id's??

Comment: Do `p2$render()` to get the entire html.